# I can't get eclipse to upload the most recent apk file to the emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

So for my app I decided to test out the use of the accelerometer. To do this I decided to run my file on my actual device. I connected the device, installed all of the drivers and ran the app and it was fine. Then when I disconnected the device, made some changes, saved, and tried to run the app with some changes on the emulator it would not change at all. No matter what I changed in the code, the file would always remain the same as the one I initially tested. I've tried rebooting the adb connection but nothing works. No matter what I do the file that is being run on the emulator is not updated. Any thoughts?

Comment: What does your console read?

Comment: Well, after reading another post I decided to 'clean' the project and as a result I am getting the error "R cannot be resolved as a variable"

Comment: Then find out which of your resources prevents your project from being built. Eclipse marks the files gives you information in Console and Problem tabs.

Comment: That error usually means that there was a problem in your resources somewhere; likely a syntax error in the .xml files. If you're using Eclipse, look for a "Problems" tab at the bottom and open it. It will likely let you know what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably an error in one of your `xml` files like others have said. I used to have problems with that all the time, but as long as there are no errors you should be fine. If you have checked, and still can't you can do `projects -> clean` or just restart eclipse. If that still doesn't work if you delete `R.java` and clean it should rebuild itself.